# ¿Por qué el compilador me sugiere este cambio?

Tags: c#, comparaciones, sharpdevelop

Trabajo con *SharpDevelop*.

A la hora de hacer esta comprobación:

```
string aux1 = "123";
string aux2 = "456";

bool iguales = false;

if(aux1.equals(aux2))
    iguales = true;
```

El compilador, me sugiere cambiarlo por:

```
string aux1 = "123";
string aux2 = "456";

bool iguales = false;

iguales |= aux1.equals(aux2);
```

Si se analiza este código en concreto, lo hace bien, pero lo hace bien porque el booleano es `false`, pero si fuese `true` no funcionaría esta equivalencia.

¿Esto quiere decir que el compilador *"sabe"* que el `bool` antes de la comparación es `false` y por eso hace la conversión, y si fuese `true` no lo haría?

¿No sería más sencillo asignar directamente el valor de esa comparación al `bool` como en las líneas siguientes?

```
string aux1 = "123";
string aux2 = "456";

bool iguales = false;

iguales = aux1.equals(aux2);
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner iguales a true a ver si sugiere lo mismo?

Comment: Si pongo igual a true no sugiere ese cambio, por eso pongo "¿Esto quiere decir que el compilador 'sabe' que el bool antes de la comparación es false y por eso hace la conversión y si fuese true no lo haría?"

Comment: No habías especificado que lo hubieses probado. Entonces es que sí, el compilador entiende que al ser `false`puede usar el operador OR. Será una manera de reducir la cantidad de líneas  de código. Al igual que podría sugerir que asignes directamente la variable iguales al resultado de la comparación. Dependerá del editor.

Comment: Todo cambio de codigo esta basado en una regla, podes fijarte bajo que regla te lo hace? siento decirte que copie tu codigo, y a mi no me lo propone.

Comment: @Alejandro el objetivo del compilador no es reducir la cantidad de líneas de código (al fin y al cabo, al pasar a bytecode el código será mucho más grande que antes) la idea es reducir la cantidad de instrucciones o evitar instrucciones costosas. En este caso, un `if` es una instrucción mucho más costosa que una simple asignación-comparación.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Era lo que quería decir, me expresé mal. Por eso he puesto la última parte de mi comentario anterior donde digo que podría asignar directamente el valor de la comparación a la variable sin necesidad de inicializarla a falso antes. Pero si que tiene que ver con el editor (IDE), porque es el que sugiere la posibilidad de hacerlo. Se pueden desactivar las sugerencias.

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo una prueba. Usa tu código, compila y abre el ensamblado resultante con un `disassembler` como puede ser [ildasm](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler)  Luego, compila el código con la modificación que te propone y examina el resultado. Compara ambos códigos IL y seguro verás diferencia.

Comment: Buenas, creo que se debe a que un **if** va a realizar primero una comparación (_testz_ probablemente) y posteriormente un salto en función de ese resultado. La instrucción por la que ha sido sustituida es un or a nivel de bit sobre un resultado, que va a funcionar (para este caso en el que vale _false_) exactamente igual que un _or_ lógico, y por lo tanto se evita operaciones en código máquina. En cualquier caso, para confirmarlo, habría que seguir el consejo de @SergioParraGuerra

Answer (score 1):

Totalmente de acuerdo contigo
Aunque para este caso puedes hacer la asingación como te la voy a dejar a continuación.

```
string aux1 = "123";
string aux2 = "456";

bool iguales = aux1.equals(aux2);
```

Answer (score 0):

El compilador te va a sugerir evitar anidaciones utilizando operadores logicos traducibles a operaciones lógicas más sencillas.

En tu caso *dependerá del momento en el que hagas la asignación del valor*, si esta encapsulado dentro de un método de una clase, etc. y en el punto posterior que hagas el cambio puede ser equivalente o no.

Referencia: [Operador OR](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/or-assignment-operator)